# proper path to source js

Tags: javascript, html

what is the proper path to source js?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/js/jquery.tipsy.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

when i use this i got error:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

thank you..

Comment: Where is the JS file actually kept, with respect to the file in which you are trying to use it ? eg. In parent folder, in same folder, etc.

Comment: Try `http:/yoururl.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/js/jquery.tipsy.js`.

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville thank you, thats work `http:/yoururl.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/js/jquery.tipsy.js`, i try this with www and thats my fault.. so amateur.. :|

Comment: Hey, only a professional can make the mistakes of an amateur. :P

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `http:/yoururl.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/js/jquery.tipsy.js` did the trick for you. If you would be so kind as to mark this the accepted answer... :)